# Vertical Gap at End of List?

Tags: html, html-lists

I have a vertical UL list on a html page, with a sublist inside of it. At the end of the sublist, it has an unwanted gap, like a linebreak, though I can't seem to find anything in my css or html that would cause it (and my attempts at trying to get it to go away aren't working very well).

Here's what it looks like;

```
1. Item
2. Item
   1. Sub Item
   2. Sub Item

3. Item
4. Item
```

My html code:

```
<ul class="fic">
  <li class="fic"><a href="">item</li>
  <li class="fic"><a href="">item
    <ul class="fic">
      <li class="fic">item</li>
      <li class="fic">item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="fic">item</li>
  <li class="fic">item</li>
  <li class="fic">item</li>
  <li class="fic">item</li>
  <li class="fic">item</li>
  <li class="fic">item</li>
  <li class="fic">item</li>
  <li class="fic">item
    <ul class="fic">
      <li class="fic">item</li>
    </ul></li>
</ul>
```

And my css code that I was trying to use;

```
.fic ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

And since my template came with menu code for the ul used in the navigation bar, here's that;

```
#menu ul {
    display: block;
    width: 778px;
    margin: 0em auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 2.5em;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
}

#menu li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.25em 0.75em 0.25em 0.75em;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    background: #342117 url('images/hover.gif') top left repeat-x;
    color: #fffdc6;
}
```

html code for navigation menu;

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="first"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="fanart.html">Fan Art</a></li>
        <li><a href="fanfic.html">Fan Fiction</a></li>
        <li><a href="fanvid.html">Fan Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="other.html">Other</a></li>
        <li><a href="forum.html">Forum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) Inspector or similar to check what styles are being applied to the elements

Answer (score 0):

The menu styles are the culprit, need full code

Comment: I already added all of the css I have involving menus or uls. Added the html code for the menu to main post just now. Otherwise, what full code do you need? the page I'm making, all of the css?